# Правильное связывание таблиц в базе данных

Tags: база-данных

недавно задался вопросом по поводу более рационального связывания таблиц в базе данных. К примеру:

#### Первый способ

```
| tasks                      |
|----------------------------|
| id INT                     | // primary key
| title VARCHAR(20)          | // index field
| description VARCHAR (2000) |

| test_data                  |
|----------------------------|
| id INT                     | // primary key
| id_task INT                | // foreign key
| input_data VARCHAR (200)   |
| output_data VARCHAR (200)  |
```

#### Второй способ

```
| tasks                      |
|----------------------------|
| title VARCHAR(20)          | // primary key
| description VARCHAR (2000) |

| test_data                  |
|----------------------------|
| id INT                     | // primary key
| title_task VARCHAR(20)     | // foreign key
| input_data VARCHAR (200)   |
| output_data VARCHAR (200)  |
```

В данном примере изображено две таблицы(задания и тестовые данные для заданий). Мне хотелось разобраться окончательно с вопросом связывания, так как в одних книгах я видел что происходит связывание первым способом, т.е. через дополнительные поля id. В других обучающих материалах находил, что связь идет напрямую на поле содержащее какую-либо информацию. В связи с этим хотелось бы получить внятный ответ на тему когда что и как лучше применять, да и почему? Также хотелось бы использовать мнение, по поводу поля id в каждой таблице, насколько оно важно? Заранее спасибо...

Comment: Не совсем понятна связь в 1 случае. Второй способ стандартная связь 1 ко многим.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором способе используется так называемый "естественный ключ" - это первичный ключ, составленный непосредственно из пользовательских данных. В первом случае используется "суррогатный ключ", который, как правило (условно в 99,9% случаев), генерируется движком СУБД в виде последовательно возрастающих чисел, и не имеет другого назначения, кроме как быть уникальным.

У естественных ключей вроде бы даже есть свои адепты, хотя на практике я с ними не сталкивался, только пару раз в интернете видел. Основные недостатки естественного ключа:

- часто первичным полем будет не поле, а набор полей. В случае, если вы будете хранить список людей, это может быть "фамилия", "имя", "отчество" и "дата рождения", или паспортные данные ("серия", "номер", "кем выдан", "дата выдачи"), или и то и другое вместе. А когда вам потребуется связать две таблицы, вам придется хранить все эти столбцы в обеих таблицах, а потом каждый раз перечислять их в запросе:

  ```
  ... t1.first_name = t2.first_name
  and t1.last_name = t2.last_name
  and ... < еще 8 полей >
  ```
- набор полей, который был уникальным, вдруг может стать неуникальным. Например, вы решили сделать первичным ключом набор полей "фамилия", "имя", "отчество" и "дата рождения". Ждать двух людей с одинаковым набором ФИО + дата рождения долго не придется, а потом придется как-то выкручиваться.